# Animate UITextViews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uitextview

I have a View with one `UITextView` in the top half, one `UIImageView` on the bottom half and a button in the middle, between them. What I'm trying to do is every time I press the button, the `UITextView` must change the text (it gets it from a `sqlite` db). I managed to do that, but now I want to animate the text change. So I want the `UITextField` to fade out to the left, then fade in from the right with a the new text inside.

Now i followed the ViewTransition documentation and created a second `UITextView` so I can animate between them. The only problem is that animation happens to the entire view. So even the image and the button slides in every time. I just want to animate the text view(s).
How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Can you please post the code you're currently using?  That'll help us determine what you should change.

Answer (score 1):

```
[UITextView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];  
[UITextView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  
self.firstTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, 0); 
self.secondTextView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-100, 0); 
[UITextView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I tried to animate my UITextView with this code snippet but like using UIView animateWithDuration:, the UIElement just disappears instead of being animated. Is there something I forgot to add?